# Possible solutions for $f(e) = 5$ of polynomial $f$ given four values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm preparing for an exam by solving the sample questions , here is the one I'm having difficulty with:

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial such that $f (a) = f (b) = f (c) = f (d) = 3$, where $a, b, c, d $ are distinct integers.
> If $f(e) = 5$, where $e$ is an integer then $e = \ $?
>
> (A) 1
> (B) 3
> (C) 4
> (D) no real value of e is possible

My gut feeling is that the polynomial must be degree $4$ or greater because it gives the same value for at least $4$ different integers.
Is this correct?   If so, why?

Anyway, I also think $e$ should be greater than $a,b,c,d$ because the polynomial evaluates to a greater value when $e$ is substituted than when $a,b,c,d$ are substituted.
Is this correct? If so , why?

Please guide me how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you need that $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: Also, if any value of $e$ works, then adding 1 to every variable means that $e+1$ also works. Please review the question's source.

Comment: @CalvinLin Maybe . Can you please tell me how to solve the problem if that is assumed?

Comment: @CalvinLin I didn't understood your second comment.

Comment: It meant that " If $e=1$ works, then by considering the polynomial for the form $g(x) = f(x+1)$, we get that $e=2$ works. Hence, the only possible answer is (D)$."

Comment: @CalvinLin What do you mean by 'Works' ? And I checked ,  the answer is indeed D .

Comment: So, this is abusing the test, but the logic is as follows. Suppose that the answer is $e=4$, for some value of $f(x), a, b, c, d$. Then, by considering $F(x) = f(x+1)$ and $A = a-1, B=b-1, C=c-1, D=d-1$, we see that $E=e-1$ will also satisfy the condition of the question. Hence $e=3$ will still be a valid answer. So will $e=1$, and vice versa. Thus, none of them are right, leaving (D).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The polynomial $g(x)=f(x)-3$ has the roots $a,b,c,d$, so $f(x)=h(x)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)+3$.

Comment: So I get $h(e)(e−a)(e−b)(e−c)(e−d)=2$ , then what ?

Comment: Certainly, you missed the condition: $f(x)$ has integer coefficients. Then $h(x)$ also has integer coefficients. Then $e-a,e-b,e-c,e-d$ are different integers, which divide $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since f takes the value 3 at 4 distinct integers a,b,c,d, then
$$
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) \, | \, f(x)-3.
$$
If f(x) has degree smaller than 3, it must be the constant polynomial at 3. Therefore f(e)=5 is impossible.

Hope that helps,